# Can a select button be customized for mobile iOS and Android too?

Tags: html, css, mobile

In my website I have a dropdown for the desktop version that works ok, but for iPad and iPhone I want that dropdown to be replaced by a select button, with it's default beahaviour ( I like how it looks on iPhone).

My question is, can I style the select button to look exactly as my dropdown button?

Here is my [website.](http://www.pawpointer.com)

You can see the dropdowns near breeder family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android and iOS handles the select element as their own and their styling differs, what you can do is use [SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) which allows you to style the element which works well on mobile aswell.

Not the best answer but hope it helps.